# 404 error on custom domain in blogger without using www

Tags: web-applications, web, dns, http-status-code-404, blogger

My website http://www.thelyricsworld.com is registered through godaddy. The site is hosted on blogger.com. I followed all the instructions to configure the dns in godaddy account.

Currently the dns settings are:

A record:

thelyricsworld.com .......  216.239.32.21

thelyricsworld.com .......  216.239.34.21

thelyricsworld.com .......  216.239.36.21

thelyricsworld.com .......  216.239.38.21

and the CNAME settings are:

www ................... @

I also had tried earlier setting the www in CNAME to ghs.google.com

My problem is that I am not able to access the website when 'www' is not prefixed. i.e. it works with http://www.thelyricsworld.com but not with http://thelyricsworld.com.

The error image is given below when www is not used.

[image]

What changes do I need to do in dns configs inorder to make it work correctly. None of the google answers seems to help.

Comment: The DNS looks to be correct- how are you doing the web-forwarding to blogger.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing same problem. In domain setting in bloggers their provide link to redirect. See attached image :

[image: Blogger setting image]

Answer (score 1):

Try contacting GoDaddy. I have had this same problem and I e-mailed them requesting for them to look at my DNS settings and see what the problem is. They e-mailed back and they (Joe M.) corrected the errors they'd found on my DNS settings (such as A records pointing to different IP address, etc).

Comment: where to contact them?

Comment: Are you using Google Apps? If you're using GApps, e-mail _gdomains @ secureserver.net_ with your problem and specifically ask them to look into your DNS. They would answer quickly, [ or within 24 hours ]. 

Their info can be found on the **Advanced DNS Settings** in Google Apps: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/YOURDOMAINNAME.com/DomainSettingsAdvancedDns [ of course, changing YOURDOMAINNAME.com with your real domain name ]

Comment: Alternatively, you could follow below steps which solves this problem, for sure, here : http://www.techproceed.com/2014/05/custom-domain-setup-on-blogger-with.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.Got into talks with the official google person and got it sorted after  a long discusion.

You will have to redo it via Google Apps.You will have to enable a redirect.

**1.**Go to Google Apps and sign in to domain management.

**2.**Then click on domain settings.

**3.**Then click on domain Names.

**4.**Then Click on words highlighted to set a redirect via google apps and you should see it done within 3 hours or MAX 2 DAYS(though it usually does not take more than a day in the rarest case).Just follow the simple english instructions there and you should see it done. 
http://img.ctrlv.in/5138cbea1bba2.jpg